# Designing dashing for Jenkins job for recent 10 changes

Tags: ruby, jenkins, dashing

anyone did code for dashing for- last 10 changes for a job in Jenkins , which we can view on dashing?I am working on it, but it is giving error.Can anyone provide the code for the same ?

Comment: Can you provide some more detail regarding error ?

Comment: I have done with work as changes in a one job, but it shows me only the last change in that job, I want last 10 changes in a same job.